# Python DictReader -- find if specific key value in a row is not found

Tags: python, csv, row

I am working on a function to pull out of CSV specific rows. Every CSV row has a unique ID that identifies it to the function. Some IDs are missing. I want to somehow find after iterating these invalid IDs.

Example:

(a sample CSV [db_short.csv](http://pastebin.com/rVu8jVkj) with rows 1-52 and then 99)

```
import csv

def get_row(csvfile, row_id):
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as csvfile:
        newfile = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        somevalue = 'default'
        for row in newfile:
            if row['id'] == str(row_id):
                somevalue = 'id = {}'.format(row['id'])
            else:
                pass
        return somevalue

db = "db_short.csv"
flatlist = [1, 18, 42, 51, 53, 99]

new_entries = []

for i in flatlist:
    new_entries.append(get_row(db, i))
print new_entries
```

Note that flatlist includes a deliberately missing ID 53. This code predictably produces output where search for 'id' : 53' returns 'default'.

```
['id = 1', 'id = 18', 'id = 42', 'id = 51', 'default', 'id = 99']
```

I would however like to replace somevalue = 'default' with, say, a customized message alerting to a missing ID, that will only appear if DictReader went through the whole CSV and did not find any row that contains 'id' : '53' -- .

```
somevalue = '{} id missing!'.format(row_id)
```

So how do I have to change my code?

Comment: I like that you added the "row" tag. Good to know that this is not a question about columns